# Function of two Brownian Motion

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

I am new to Brownian motion, and I have problem with verifying a Brownian motion.
Let $B(t)$ be the standard Brownian motion. Is true that $W(t)=B(5t)-B(t)$ is also a Brownian motion (not necessarily standard). Thank you for any comment/hint.

My attempt: We know $W(0)=0$ holds. I tried to check the independent increments property: for any $s<t<r$, $W(t)-W(s)=B(5t)-B(t) - (B(5s)-B(s)) = B(5t)-B(5s)- (B(t)-B(s))$, and also $W(r)-W(t)=B(5r)-B(r)-(B(5t)-B(t))$. I am not sure how to proceed to prove/disprove the independence of $W(t)-W(s)$ and $W(r)-W(t)$.

Comment: What properties of Brownian Motion have you tried checking?  It has mean $0$, but what other properties does it need to have?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I tried to check independent increment. For any $s<t$, we have $B(5t)-B(t)-(B(5s)-B(s))=B(5t)-B(5s)-(B(t)-B(s))$. We know $B(t)-B(s)\sim N(0,t-s)$ and $B(5t)-B(5s)\sim N(0,5(t-s))$. But I am not sure how to proceed, because $B(5t)-B(5s)$ and $B(t)-B(s)$ are dependent.

Comment: Variance of $B(5t)-B(t)$ is not $t$ , so it cannot be a standard BM.

Comment: $EB(u)B(v)=E[(B(v)-B(u)] B(u)+EB^{2}(u)=E[(B(v)-B(u)] EB(u)+EB^{2}(u)=0+u=u$ for $u <v$.

Comment: $var (B(v)-B(u))$ is $v-u$.

Comment: Sorry I got confused. You are right. $Var(B(5t)-B(t))=4t$. But again, I am not sure how to prove this is not a Brownian motion. In your comment above, I do not quite get why variance of $B(5t)-B(t)$ should be $t$. Do you mean $4t$?

Comment: Hi Xu and welcome to MSE.  Add the clarification in your first comment into the question.

Comment: Hi @samerivertwice. Thank you. I clarified the question.

Comment: Good work  Some people get upset if you don't show your workings.

Answer (score 1):

What is a *standard* Brownian Motion? One of the properties is that Var(B(t)) = t.

This process $W(t) = B(5t)-B(t)$ does not satisfy this property, so it cannot be a *standard* Brownian Motion.

However, a *general* Brownian Motion has stationary increments, but the process $W(t)$ is not even stationary:
$$\begin{aligned}
W(t+h)-W(t) &= B(5t+5h)-B(t+h)-(B(5t)-B(t)) = \\
            &= [B(5t+5h)-B(5t)] - [B(t+h)-B(t)] .
\end{aligned} $$

For $h$ small enough, $5t > t+h$, then the random variables $B(5t+5h)-B(5t)$ and $B(t+h)-B(t)$ are independent since $B$ has independent increments. Furthermore, by definition of $B$,
$$ B(5t+5h)-B(5t) \sim \mathcal{N}(0,5h) $$
$$ B(t+h)-B(t) \sim \mathcal{N}(0,h) .$$

If we sum (resp. subtract) two independent gaussian random variables, we obtain another gaussian random variable with mean equals to the sum (resp. the difference) of the means and variance equals to the sum of the variances. So
$$ W(t+h)-W(t) = [B(5t+5h)-B(5t)] - [B(t+h)-B(t)] \sim \mathcal{N}(0,6h) ,$$
while
$$ W(h) = B(5h) - B(h) \sim \mathcal{N}(0,4h). $$

Comment: I think in the definition of BM, the increments are Gaussian random variables. In general, Var(B(t)) could be $\sigma^2$. In the standard BM, we have $\sigma=1$. I know $B(5t)-B(t)$ is not a standard BM, but I cannot see why it cannot be BM. For instance, does it violate the independent increment property?

Comment: I was thinking at standard BM. I edited the answer adding a new argument

Comment: Thank you very much! This makes sense.